# Is it safer to user Integer PrimaryKey + Hashing or use secrets module without hashing

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database

I am trying to create an application that requires some sensitive data. Now inside my database, I am using the python secrets module to create a safe 16-byte hex token for each object. However, by doing so I will not be able to hash it as it's not an integer anymore. So I was wondering if I use the `secrets` module will it be safe enough to expose the id's to the end-users?

so for instance I have a field for one of my tables in my database such that:

`id = secrets.token_hex(16)`
which for instance would return  `id = cf125cf14d4ae9ed8972ee7512755e6d`

Or should I stick to the regular database primary keys which are auto-incremented integers and then use a hashing library to show the hashed value and then just decode those when I want to use them?

Comment: Safer is relative.  What threats are you protecting against?  Once you have determined what threats exist, then you can determine the best approach to securing the data.

Comment: This is for to keep track of private chatrooms. So in the URL users will see the id of the chatroom, so that's essentially what I'm protecting.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use uuids as primary keys for all entities.

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class SomeModel(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(
        default = uuid.uuid4,
        editable = False,
        primary_key = True,
    )
```